# Is there a way to switch on return types so that the compiler knows that the return type and matched type are the same?

Tags: generics, rust, unsafe

How can I avoid using unsafe code in the code below? It's meant to be part of an entity-component-system library. More generally, is there a way to switch on return types in Rust in a way that the compiler will know inside the block that the return type and matched type are the same?

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)] struct Health(f64);
#[derive(Debug)] struct Position([f64; 3]);

trait Entity {
    fn get<'a, T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&'a T>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Pig {
    health: Health,
    position: Position,
}

impl Entity for Pig {
    fn get<'a, T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<Health>() {
            Some(unsafe {mem::transmute(&self.health)})
        } else if TypeId::of::<T>() == TypeId::of::<Position>() {
            Some(unsafe {mem::transmute(&self.position)})
        } else { None }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let waddles = Pig {
        health: Health(2.0),
        position: Position([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]),
    };

    println!("Waddles' Health: {:?}", waddles.get::<Health>());
}
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/d60625ae7f7539a58603)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
fn get<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    if let Some(health) = Any::downcast_ref::<T>(&self.health) {
        Some(&health)
    }
    else if let Some(position) = Any::downcast_ref::<T>(&self.position) {
        Some(&position)
    } else { 
        None 
    }
}
```

Note that I also removed the explicit lifetime from the function header (in the trait definition, too). Lifetime elision works in this case, as the output-lifetime is bound to the input-lifetime (`self`).

The above code is pretty verbose and has a lot of duplicate code. So it could be useful to write a simple macro for it:

```
macro_rules! entity_match {
    ($self_:ident; $($entity:ident),*) => {{
        $(if let Some(inner) = Any::downcast_ref::<T>(&$self_.$entity) {
            return Some(&inner);
        })*
        None
    }}
}

impl Entity for Pig {
    fn get<T: Any>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        entity_match!(self; health, position)
    }
}
```

As a little note: I think it would be pretty nice to use compiler plugins here, to mark some struct members as entities in the struct definition.

Comment: Wow, that's nice to know, I planned on learning compiler plugins with this project :) And uh, you probably already knew, but you can avoid the cast with Any::downcast_ref(&self.health) instead, which is even cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: This should probably be another question, but do you any way this can be used in trait objects? I mean, I probably should've thought of that first.

Comment: @Shien It's difficult. You would need to return the component as a trait object, too. But as you said, it's enough for another question -- maybe in the Rust user forum, instead of SO...